# Four eye principle using ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

Some of our workflows require a second user to confirm the action by a higher level authority. Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Core Identity in such a way that a second user can authenticate on the website and grant authorization to a certain action for a short period of time (e.g. 15 seconds)?

The workflows are mostly consisting of five steps:

- User clicks element to execute action
- Login prompt for higher level authority
- Successful login of authority
- Action gets executed
- Refresh the authorized state of the higher level authority

Even if it is configurable in such a way, would it be a viable option? Or would it be faster to implement such a solution myself?

Best regards

Comment: Would removing the authority at the end of the action execution work for you?

Comment: Not really. I missed mention a crucial detail in the requirement. The authorization of the authority should be valid for a certain period of time (e.g. 15 seconds) and refresh itsself everytime the action is executed. This is required for workstations where a higher level authority and a non-permitted user are working hand in hand. Removing the authority after the action requires the user to authorize on every action while it should be done fluently without any interruption. Thanks for the comment, i'll edit the question and add the detail in the requirement.

Comment: I would change the workflow so that the actions of user 1 need a second authorization by independent user 2, ie 2 explicit states. Workflows where a user raises his/her hand and a nearby supervisor swipes a card or types a magic auth bypass typically get abused (secret is shared or the access card handed around the floor). Post Covid, sharing of computers and users in close proximity will become rarer.

Comment: When a user click the element, it will skip into a filter which prompt a login page for higher level authority. Then the login page will redirect to the action and assign a Temporary permission to the user. And the permission (token) has a expiration time. 
Can you accept the above procedure?

Comment: @StuartLC This is the exact way the workflow works. Authority gets called and they do work side by side, that's why a refresh is necessary to avoid multiple login prompts. The question is, can IdentityServer handle that kind of workflow? I didn't get any smarter looking at the official documentation.

Comment: @Karney We need the credentials of the authority for the protocol. Therefore, just adding a temporary permission is not an option.